# How to avoid passing around runtime parameter everywhere

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a client app that let's user take part in a match. In almost all cases, maybe except tests, user takes part in one or zero matches at the same time. Every match have a unique ID, let's call it MatchID. I have many services that provides information about the match, e.g.:

```
interface IMatchPlayersRepository
{
    string[] GetMatchPlayers(string matchId);
    string GetBestPlayer(string matchId);
}

interface IMatchFieldsInfo
{
    int GetFieldSize(string matchId);
}

interface IMatchScoreboardProvider
{
    Scoreboard GetScoreboard(string matchId, string someOtherParam);
}

// And many others...
```

Implementations of those use one another, e.g.:

```
public class MatchScoreboardProvider : IMatchScoreboardProvider
{
    public MatchScoreboardProvider(IMatchPlayersRepository playersRepository)
    { //...
    }

    public Scoreboard GetScoreboard(string matchId, string someOtherParam)
    {
        var bestPlayer = _playersRepository.GetBestPlayer(matchId);
        //...
    }
}
```

How do I prevent passing `matchId` everywhere? Using factories only moves the problem to factory methods, e.g.:

```
public class MatchPlayersRepositoryFactory
{
    public IMatchPlayersRepository Get(string matchId) => new MatchPlayersRepository(matchId);
}

public class MatchScoreboardProvider : IMatchScoreboardProvider
{
    // Created from factory
    public MatchScoreboardProvider(string matchId, MatchPlayersRepositoryFactory playersRepositoryFactory)
    { //...
    }

    public Scoreboard GetScoreboard(string someOtherParam)
    {
        var bestPlayer = _playersRepositoryFactory.Get(_matchId).GetBestPlayer();
        //...
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would have another DI "composition root" for every match, where all object are created from this new DI framework, that passes `matchId` to them. However, creating a new "composition root" seems like a really bad idea, from what I understand.

Comment: is this app an asp.net web API?

Comment: @fbede no, sorry

Comment: Here is a good article to read about that topic https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/

Comment: Besides the article @Nkosi suggests, I'd also suggest [this series on Composition Models](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/di-composition-models-primer/).

Comment: The `matchId` parameter is perfectly appropriate in the interfaces you've provided.  Maybe those aren't the interfaces you really need.  It can be difficult to make a contrived example that captures your real problem.  Many of the interfaces you didn't provide could probably use an `IMatch` facade.  They shouldn't have dependencies on all the various services, anyway.